# Difference between the local modifications to two checkouts

Tags: svn, local, checkout, difference

I have checked out a same repository twice using svn in two different folders. Then I made local modifications to both checkouts. I would like to find out the difference between the local modifications made to these two checkouts.

Comment: You could just use `diff`. The fact that these are working copies seems irrelevant.

Comment: I did diff in the past, but i was wondering if svn have any swiss army knife.

Comment: Actual this question is not limited to SVN. You could you any tool which offers file comparison, e.g. BeyondCompare